# How to know when to use a singly linked list or a grounded header linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Given a problem, how can I analyse which one is better? I know what is each one, but I don't know the difference in terms of when to use or when not to use.

Comment: How did your search for 'grounded header linked list' not come up with any good links?

Comment: I'll follow the answer, and add one additional distinction. Your grounded linked list can only be iterated from `head->tail` as the last `->next` is always `NULL`. The second variant discussed a *circular linked list* has the final `->next` point back to `head` allowing you to traverse the list from any node, around the list back to that node crossing `tail->head`. A circular list requires a bit more care for insert and delete as you must test for a final self-referencing node. If you don't need to iterate from any node, then stick with a basic list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most singly linked lists are [grounded header linked lists](http://www.topsomethingup.com/2013/08/header-and-grounded-header-list.html), where the last element in the list has a null pointer as the 'next' pointer.  Occasionally, people use circular linked lists, but that's the special case that needs the special terminology.

Note that a linked list could have a loop in it (not necessarily back to the first node), in which case it won't be a grounded linked list, and you need special code to spot that there is a loop.  You can have one or several tails that link into the loop of such a linked list.

```
A    D              E         B
@--->@--->@--->@--->@<---@<---@
     ^              |
     |              v    C
     @<---@<---@<---@<---@
     G              F
```

Each of A, B, and C is the start of a linked list that ends up in the cycle D, E, F, G.  However, such linked lists are aberrant — they're unusual and usually undesirable, and usually if such a list is created, it is a symptom of a bug.

Use a grounded linked list unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.